# Facebook comment box not working in iPhone / Safari

Tags: iphone, facebook, safari, facebook-social-plugins

I have a page integrated with Facebook comment box (social plugin) which work perfectly in desktop browser, however it's not working when I use a iPhone to browse the page, a Facebook "loading" keep showing and the comment box didn't come out.

I have tired the following too:

1. Browse the same page with a Android phone, OK
2. Browse the same page with a iphone 3rd party browser (I use a QR code scanner browser), OK
3. Browse the same page with iphone safari, NOT OK

I found this bug report at facebook at Jan, but no response: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/171818679588280?browse=search_4f26fb988bf8d0c61735624

Anyone have an idea on this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

there is no iframe code for the comments plugin - the html5 code works, but it doesn't resize for the iphone, which causes lots of layout problems. I used a conditional css for iphone sized: ( you have to wrap the code in a div with class "facebook-wrap")

```
@media screen and (max-width: 460px) { 
.facebook-wrap iframe {
width:300px!important;
left:0!important;
position:relative!important;
max-width:100%;
}
.comments_wrap.section{padding:0}
```

Comment: I guess the issue happen due to iOS version - actually I'm already using HTML5 code, however its work in one machine which in iOS 5, but failed in another machine which in iOS 4. 
Anyway thanks for your reply:)

Answer (score 0):

Use the "iframe" code instead of the javascript